# NASM: replace a specific bit of a register by a flag

Tags: string, replace, bit-manipulation, nasm, bit

There's a quick query in nasm :

How can I xor a flag and a specific bit from a register ? I don't know the syntax for that concretly.
What I need is to replace the last bit of a register by a flag value

Thx for your help to that simple question !

Comment: Which flag specifically? Look up the `SETcc` instructions in Intel's manual.

Comment: Oh yeah Thank you. Dont have it in my cursus ... So i dont knew it.
SALC can be usefull too ( set AL from carry ) .
Thx for answer, especially if someone next need it ;) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've founded a way more easier ( cause i dont found a way for moving a value from a flag to a register )

I just make a ROL on my first value (insteed of a SHR) and applyed a mask AND to keep the last value and assign it after that.